# ubuntu 64 bit installation on VMWare Workstation

Tags: windows, vmware

Trying to install **16.04 LTS** ISO on my laptop running Windows 10 using VMware workstation. It had run more than an hour, but the installation was still going. I pressed <kbd>F1</kbd> to see the installation log and found that the installation is stuck at this line

```
Generating Locales (this might take a while)...
```

Here is the  full error message

[image: full error message]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation nor the right answer but if it was my system, I would select the **en_US** locale during installation and then localize later.